# imagemagic installation issue in xampp windows

Tags: php, imagemagick, extension-methods

I was trying to install ImageMagick but had no luck

Step follow

Downloaded an extra dll in `php/ext` folder
Copied files in `apache/bin` folder

Added extension refer in `php.ini` file but still no luck

Comment: I would suggest you do a Google search for installation of ImageMagick on xamp or search the ImageMagick Discourse server User's forum at https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/. See for example, https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/349/how-to-install-and-enable-the-imagick-extension-in-xampp-for-windows

Comment: So you are actually trying to install Imagick the php API for Imagemagick?

Comment: Thanks for your help after copying in apache bin problems solver.